# Outlook version 1910 failing after requiring MFA (old password prompt loop)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I flipped several users over to start using MFA for their Office365 login.  Now about 2/3 of them are getting continual "Enter password" prompts with the old style password prompt. The few users I was able to fix it was because I happen to spot a "toaster pop" stating outlook needed a password, and clicking on that brought us to the new style password prompt. I knew other versions had this problem so I made sure they were all updated before flipping over.

I've notices that Microsoft Teams will always prompt with the new version. Other o365 products (word/excel) will also prompt with the new style after using the "fix me" option under File> Office Account> User Information.

Things I've tried:

- reboots (both on their own and after every step)
- regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity
  DisableADALatopWAMOverride dword value 1
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity
  EnableADAL dword value 1
- Used a APP password when password is requested

There are plenty of blog and support pages, but it appears no solution has is better then the others. Please let me know other items people have tried. I saw something about removing local stored Outlook data, which made some since as all other Office produces were ok, but the instructions were unclear. I have a few dozen users still to activate MFA on and I need a better plan for the next batch.

Comment: What does “I flipped several users over to MFA,” mean? What documentation did you follow. Did you enable modern authentication on your tenant?

Comment: Office.com> Admin > Users> Active Users> Multi-factor authentication  then selected employees who were not using MFA

Admin> Settings> Services & Add-ins > Modern Authentication  this filed is not active.

Of the ~125 users only were identified as needing to use MFA ~25 do not have it active at this time.

Comment: “Did you enable modern authentication on your tenant?”

Comment: @Appleoddity Modern Authentication is not active on the account. Probably because it's an older account. As it has been working for a majority of users without this active do you know of what users could experience once MA is activated? We also have some 3rd parties who have accounts on our system who in no cases would be required to use a MFA, I would need a change management request for a system wide change.

Comment: Modern authentication is REQUIRED if you are using MFA. This is why I asked about what documentation you followed? This is the documentation you should have followed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?view=o365-worldwide - it should be enabled for skype, exchange and sharepoint. I'm not aware of any problems. As an office 365 customer you have access to support. I suggest you talk to Microsoft about your concerns. You should also make sure you are running the latest office client, or at least 2016.

Comment: Also, you should explore the use of conditional access policies rather than turning on MFA like you did. I know this is complicated, but conditional access policies allow you to bypass MFA for recognized devices and certain IP addresses, or other conditions. You don't want users constantly having to perform MFA if they are on company provided devices or in the office. To switch you would need to find and run a powershell script that removes the MFA setting you turned on but does not erase the MFA methods the user has configured.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

There was no documentation, only an internal "how we've done stuff in the past" guide. As there were several people currently using the assumption was the guide was correct.

Comment: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/36213742-disable-mfa-without-erasing-settings and https://thomasrayner.ca/script-share-disable-azure-ad-mfa-without-wiping-user-options/ gives an idea how to switch to conditional access policies which requires turning off MFA settings that you turned on but keeping the MFA authentication methods that users already configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was indeed related to old credentials. To fix this problem I had to do the following:

1. Logout: this includes Teams and Office products. There was a "force log-out of all accounts" in the users office365 web portal which some users were able to find, but I can no longer find which made this much easier.
2. Regedit: to rename folders for the old outlook profile, 2 offending folders were:  **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook**   & **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook**
3. Windows Control Panel: to confirmed no mailbox data was associated with the account anymore.
4. o365 Admin portal: to activated MFA for the user.
5. User logged into office.com to complete their MFA setup. Saved "app password for good measure".
6. User downloaded and installed newest Office bundle from office.com. Correcting registry build form step 2
7. After install of Office bundle used Office app to login with MFA
8. Opened outlook and selected the new "outlook" mail profile generated in part by step 7.
9. Confirmed office365 mailbox type
10. Confirmed outlook re-downloaded mail data and profile persisted though reboots

After some practice this was down to 10 - 15 minutes per user. With the Office re-install taking much of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Some general reasons are recorded in this [Forum FAQ](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook). You may try removing previous cached credential to test the results.

Besides, it could also be caused by Outlook limits its choices of authentication schemes to schemes that are supported by RPC. This does not include Modern Authentication. Refer to [this official article.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3126599/outlook-prompts-for-password-when-modern-authentication-is-enabled) to check AlwaysUseMSOAuthForAutoDiscover registry key.